# work done by a gas compressed or decompressed by a piston

Tags: thermodynamics, work, gas

checking these two ideas:

if a gas is confined in a container and is closed from one side by a piston, and we gradually move the piston so that the volume occupied by the gas increases, the work done by the gas in this case is 0, is that right?

also in the same way, the piston is now compressing the gas, the work done by the gas is still 0 in this case, correct?

Comment: Mention the reason(s), why you think the way you thought here.

Comment: the piston is being moved externally, so the gas has no effect on it, so the gas does no work here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of basic research.

Comment: @Gert (and other close voters): While we've done this for a while, *closing* questions for lack of effort is somewhat controversial. What is *not* controversial is downvoting them - the downvoting tooltip explicitly calls out "no research effort" as a reason for downvoting. That four people voted to close this question for lack of effort but not a single one downvoted it is inconsistent.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I don't like down voting much. This question would take 5 mins of googling. Is that what we want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correct! When the piston moves out so that the volume increases, the gas performs work on the piston. When you  compress the  gas with the piston you perform work on the gas.

Comment: but the piston is being moved manually, ie the gas isn't the one doing the work

Comment: By moving a surface area A of the gas enclosure (piston) , the gas molecules do a work W= p·A l (p pressure, A piston area, l shift of piston) on the this piston. Who moves the piston is irrelevant. Microscopically the work done by the gas molecules is due to the fact that they are reflected at a lower than the incident speed and thus lose momentum and energy  when the piston is moved outward.